# TEXTAREA получение value с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form id="customer__form" action="#">
        <label for="name">Введите ФИО</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" placeholder="ФИО" id="customer__name" checked>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label for="description">Описание</label>
        <br />
        <textarea name="description" id="customer__description" cols="100" rows="10" maxlength="1000" checked></textarea>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label for="data">Введите дату</label>
        <br />
        <input type="week" name="data" id="customer__data" checked>
        <br />
        <input type="reset" id="reset">
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="done">
    </form>


const customerForm = document.getElementById('customer__form');

const obj = {};

for(const elem of customerForm.elements){
        if(elem.tagName === 'INPUT' && elem.checked){
            obj[elem.name] = elem.value;
        }
    }

    bodyLog.push(obj);

    console.log(bodyLog);
```

Выводит только это (input), а textarea нет {name: "Имя Фамилия О", data: "2020-W02"}

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('customer__form').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function g() {
  var cf = document.getElementById('customer__form')
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Array.prototype.filter.call(cf.querySelectorAll('input'),
      (el) => el.checked
    ).concat(cf.querySelector('textarea')).map((el) => [el.name, el.value])
  )
}

// только для просмотра
document.getElementById('done').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(g())
})
```

```html
<form id="customer__form" action="#">
  <label for="name">Введите ФИО</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" placeholder="ФИО" id="customer__name" checked>
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="description">Описание</label>
  <br />
  <textarea name="description" id="customer__description" cols="100" rows="10" maxlength="1000" checked></textarea>
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="data">Введите дату</label>
  <br />
  <input type="week" name="data" id="customer__data" checked>
  <br />
  <input type="reset" id="reset">
  <br />
  <input type="submit" id="done">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1)Добавляешь имя форме

```
<form ***name="cF"*** id="customer__form">
        <label for="name">Введите ФИО</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" placeholder="ФИО" id="customer__name" checked>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label for="description">Описание</label>
        <br />
        <textarea name="description" id="customer__description" cols="100" rows="10" maxlength="1000" checked></textarea>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label for="data">Введите дату</label>
        <br />
        <input type="week" name="data" id="customer__data" checked>
        <br />
        <input type="reset" id="reset">
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="done">
    </form>
```

2)Создаешь новую переменную для textarea и обращаешься к нему вот так:
let customerDescription2 = document.cF.description.value;
3)Потом вводишь его в объект:
obj[elem.name] = elem.value;
Полный код js:

```
//Получение всех элементов
    const obj = {}; 

    for(const elem of customerForm.elements){
        if(elem.tagName === 'INPUT' && elem.checked){
            obj[elem.name] = elem.value;
        }
        ***let customerDescription2 = document.cF.description.value;
        obj[elem.name] = elem.value;***
    }

    bodyLog.push(obj);

    console.log(bodyLog);
```